# Problem with displacement maps

Tags: uv

I'm not so familiar with Blender and have a problem with displacement map.
I use software called "CrazyBump" and it generates specularity, displacement, occlusion, color and normal maps itself.

My intention is to make plaster material which is the material of the wall look more realistic. That' s why I want to use displacement map to change the look of the wall. However, it somehow won't work like this. The material of the wall is not changing its' shape, it's the wall itself..

The displacement map is right under this text:

[image: Displacement map]

I really tend to think that something is really wrong with my displacement map and doesn' t work right.

So here's the house with displacement map.
[image]

I am clueless what to do next as I have tried fixing this problem on my own for whole day already and nothing seems to be working. Maybe some of you have encountered this problem earlier and could suggest any solutions..

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. It's not very clear in your images or your explanation.

Comment: The *Displace modifier* will modify the positions of the actual vertices in the mesh. Sounds like maybe you just want to the displacement in the material, and delete the modifier?

Comment: Could you show the image that you gave Crazy Bump to generate this displacement map?

Answer (score 1):

The source for the displacement map in this case has to be an image or procedural texture, not the model itself. One way to do what you want would be to get or create tileable plaster texture first (look for "tile plaster texture bump" on a search engine), then create a material just for the walls, assign it and unwrapp the walls as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mesh topology that is much more highly subdivided before you'll see anything noticeable from the Displacement modifier.

I would move the SubSurf modifier above the displacement modifier and turn up the subdivisions until you start to see the effect. Also the displacement texture is pretty subtle, so you many need to turn up the values pretty high to see it take place.

In addition you may get the effect you want with just a normal map instead of true mesh displacement if you you're just going for a subtle uneven surface for plaster. If so, it would require much less resources for rendering if you could.